# What is the best way to get around the Error 200 in October CMS version 2 when running deploy to server?

Tags: deployment, ftp, octobercms, octobercms-plugins, octobercms-backend

Error Below when deploying (with the Deploy App) the core archive of October CMS version 2

Is shows that it is seeing the beacon, but still gives error below.

Update Failed

A valid response from a beacon was not found. Add ?debug=1 to your URL, try again and check the logs (Code: 200)

Comment: maybe do adding `?debug=1` in URL and check logs and post it here for more details

Comment: which url? would it be the one for the server or the localhost

I.e www.huismancreative.co.za/backend?debug=1 or localhost/HCco?backend?debug=1